# Synchronous Buck Converter loop function

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, switching-regulator, step-down

I have been reading the data of this Buck converter model, but on the block diagram scheme. I don't understand what does the indicated feedback loop do.

[image]

The buck Convert model is LM5165-Q1 and this is the link the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5165-q1.pdf).

Comment: The voltage feedback? Measures the output and compensates the duty cycle to keep the output voltage at the desired value.

Comment: fwiw, the highlighted low side nmos is not part of the feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms the output of a synchronous buck regulator is input supply voltage x duty cycle. So, for a given duty cycle the output voltage follows the input voltage by this factor (duty cycle).

This doesn't make a very good regulator so feedback is used that measures the output voltage against a reference voltage and adjusts the duty cycle so that the output voltage is correct.